# Use of TF vs odometry information

Tags: control, navigation, odometry, pose, learning-tf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I started using Ros a while ago to acquire information from some sensors for robot control and I ran into the following doubt.

I understand how TF works, although i'm still figuring out transforms, but I don't fully get why is it better to use the TFs instead of the odometry information directly from the sensors. I have made two codes that are very much identical, but one reads the TF information, while the other reads the sensors' odometry/pose topics and they both seem to work.

Every package seems to go through the trouble of building a tf tree and that adds latency. Isn't it easier to work with the raw sensor outputs?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213388/use-of-tf-vs-odometry-information/) by [MaryC](https://answers.ros.org/users/22575/maryc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-07-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Latency is not a problem as everything is timestamped and the correct data is retrieved. Either way, you need to get odometry or tf messages.

The huge advantage is that tf does not only provide the odometry pose of the robot, but the pose of every link in the TF tree over time. If you want to know, where your laser is in the /odom frame, tf gets you this directly without manually puzzling together transformations.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1